# Difference between git merge master and origin/master?

Tags: git

Result of the command `git merge origin/master`:

```
javanoob@DELL:~/workspace/PROJECT_One$ git merge origin/master 
Updating d83ef9c..dd520ea
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    sample.txt
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Result of the command `git merge master`:

```
javanoob@DELL:~/workspace/PROJECT_One$ git merge master
Already up-to-date.
```

When I do the command `git merge origin/master` It shows that there are some files which will be overwritten but if I do the same command without the prefix `origin/` it says everything is already up-to-date.

What is wrong in this setup?

I don't know if it matters but before running these commands, I did run the command `git fetch origin`

Comment: there is no difference between your local master branch and your remote ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab, My local master branch is up to date with the remote master branch. I am trying to merge master branch into my current branch because my current branch does not have few commits which are present in master branch.

Comment: Have you tried `git pull origin master` in your local master branch and try to run the above commands again, and see if there is a difference ?

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab, I thought `git fetch origin` command will update local master branch with changes from remote master branch. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @javanoob it will list branches with changes and download the objects for you, but the merge or pull , this is your call

Comment: Today ( 2022 ) the command is "git merge origin/main"

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`git fetch` fetches information on remote branches, but does not make any changes to your local `master` branch. Because of this, `master` and `origin/master` are still diverged. You'd have to merge them by using `git pull`.

When you make a commit, your local `master` branch is ahead of `origin/master` until you push those changes. This case is the opposite, where the `origin/master` branch is ahead of your local `master` branch. This is why you are getting different outcomes.

Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/7104747/2961170 for more information.

Comment: you are the first one to understand what I am trying to do here :)

Answer (score 10):

Using `git merge origin/master` refers to the master branch on the server. `git merge master` refers to your local master branch.

By using `git pull` you can merge them if they diverge.

Comment: I did `git fetch origin`. I thought git fetch command updates local branch with changes from remote branch..Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: `git pull` does a `git fetch` and a `git merge` (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/5712053)). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: does `git merge origin/master` always use the latest master from remote? Like, does it perform a `git fetch origin/master` automatically? And if so, how does git track this `origin/` differently from the rest

Comment: `git merge` does not perform a `git fetch`, of course. I encourage you to try it out, I think that makes things clearer. To update `origin/master`, run `git fetch` yourself.

Answer (score 8):

`master` is your local branch, `origin/master` is remote branch (the state it was at last `fetch`)

The output you have shows that there's a commit in remote, that will overwrite `sample.txt` and is not yet `pull`'ed into your local `master`

As a rule of thumb - it's always better to have a clean working tree and up-to-date branches before doing any merging/rebasing etc.

So - commit your work, check git status, then do `git pull --rebase` ('oh-my-zsh' has alias `gup` for this) and only then proceed with merging.