# git merge origin master doesn't work

Tags: git

```
git status
```

It will get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Then if I run

```
git fetch -a && git merge origin master
```

It will get:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

I wonder why can't I get a merge operation?

Comment: instead of `git fetch -a` try `git fetch --all`

Comment: @Code_Ninja It still won't merge as his local HEAD will be pointing to his working branch and not his updated remote branch. He could use `FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: okay.. yes surely, I am bit new to git. I am still in the process of learning.

Answer (score 4):

```
git fetch && git merge origin/master
```

is different from

```
git fetch && git merge origin master # Invalid
```

because `git fetch` updates `.git/refs/remote/<remote server name>/<remote branch name>`. And unless specified, you're always referring to your `HEAD` of the working directory, which is in `.git/refs/heads/<branch name>`

**Note:** `git merge` is a local operation. `git merge origin master` is an  invalid operation. As discussed here [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626304/difference-between-git-merge-branch-and-git-merge-origin-branch)

**Git fetch**
`git fetch` fetches information on remote branches, but does not make any changes to your local `master` branch. Because of this, `master` and `origin/master` are still diverged. You'd have to merge them by using `git pull` 
When you make a commit, your local master branch is ahead of `origin/master` until you push those changes. This case is the opposite, where the `origin/master` branch is ahead of your local master branch. This is why you are getting different outcomes

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34496988/5698740)

Answer (score 3):

When you do `git merge origin master`, both `origin` and `master` are interpreted as branch names. However `origin` refers to another repository (called a remote), not a branch. You can perform this action with a simple change:

```
git fetch && git merge origin/master
```

Here `origin/master` refers to a remote tracking branch. This is a local copy of the branch which was fetched from the `origin` remote. Alternatively you can just do

```
git pull origin master
```

Or since you already are on the `master` branch, you can do

```
git pull
```

Comment: I should have given more effort for my answer.

Comment: @ClamentJohn Your answer is good. If you feel it needs some improvement, just click the "edit" link just below it. Then make the changes and save it.

Comment: thanks! you guys have all told us what origin/master is, and why we should use origin/master in this case. But you didn't tell us why "origin master" doesn't work...

Comment: @zzzgoo I attempted to explain why `git merge origin master` doesn't work at the beginning of my master. If you need more information, I suggest that you run `git help merge` for more details about how merging works.