# Difference between git merge <branch> and git merge origin <branch>

Tags: git, git-merge

This is not a question on `git merge origin branch` vs `git merge origin/branch`

`git merge <branch>` merges the  into the working branch. And so we need to specify the "source" of the branch. It can be a locally available `origin/<branch>` or the local working branch `heads/branch`.

But what's the need for `origin`? Unlike `git pull` we don't need to specify which remote source to fetch the  from. A merge operation, to my understanding, is a local operation.

Comment: Note that, syntactically, `git merge origin branch` is like writing `git merge A B`. *Both arguments are treated as names.* The name `origin` *means* `origin/HEAD` as you can see in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html), so this is equivalent to `git merge origin/HEAD branch`. That calls for an *octopus merge* unless `origin/HEAD` is already merged or maps to an ancestor of `branch`. (The TL;DR version of all of this is ***never run `git merge origin branch`*** as it means something you *don't want*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git pull` command lets you specify a default remote branch to be used for fetching, as well as the default target local branch as the merge target.  It makes sense to do this, because typically a given local branch will only have one upstream on the remote.

On the other hand, the `git merge` operation could be happening with *any* source branch, with your local branch as the target.  Therefore, it makes less sense to allow for defining a default source branch to be used in merging.

The one instance where a default source branch for merging would make sense is of course `git pull`, when you want to update your local version of the remote branch.  But, this merge scenario is actually part of `git pull`, and usually is not done a separate merge.

Comment: Yes, `git merge` can happen from any source. But specifying `git merge origin master` doesn't download from origin (`git fetch -all`). So isn't the `origin` argument useless?

Comment: @ClamentJohn `git merge origin master` is not valid Git syntax, AFAIK.  When you merge in Git locally, you always do it with _local_ branches.  Keep in mind that even `origin/master` is still a _local_ branch, which just happens to track the actual branch which is on the remote.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused. So, `git merge` is a local operation and `git merge origin master` isn't a valid operation. Or git just ignores the users ignorance!

Comment: Yeah...I was sort of wondering whether that was even running for you.  I've never done a merge using that syntax, nor do you have to.

Comment: I havn't. I was just making sure for a question I answered on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625133/git-merge-origin-master-doesnt-work